# Is that possible to throw errors with respect to a StateFlow in the view model and catch them in the activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I am using StateFlow to host UI states and MutableStateFlow as backing property in my ViewModel class. Let's suppose my property is called uiState and initialized as follows:

```
private var _uiState = MutableStateFlow(SomeData(message="NONE"))
val uiState: StateFlow<SomeData>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

I know that I can update _uiState by

```
_uiState.update {it.copy(message="Some message")}
```

then in my Activity I can collect the data like this:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        launch { 
            viewModel.uiState.collect { data ->
                // Get data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I throw errors in my view model and then catch it in the activity?

I mean is that possible to somehow throw errors like this

```
_uiState.update {
    // Throwing error? How?
}
```

In my view model and then catch it in the Activity as:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        launch {
            viewModel.uiState
                .catch {
                    // Catch error
                }
                .collect { data ->
                    // Get data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think when we create a flow using `flow {}` we can throw errors in the block and then catch it like above code; but what about StateFlow ?

Comment: I would not throw an error, instead I would create an error state and emit that value.